# Computing average of data in multiple (different) columns in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a SPSS data file, which i am trying to reduce. However the data which belongs together is spread within multiple columns. I.e. I have one row per subject, but each subject has done multiple different conditions as well as procedures. The conditions are in columns `condition_1`, `condition_2` etc. The procedures are in rows `procedure_1`, `procedure_2` etc. The values (reaction times) are in columns `reaction_time_1`, `reaction_time_2`. Now I want to compute the average of all reactions times for each person where the condition and procedure is the same. So if `condition_x` is the same as `condition_y` and `procedure_x` is the same as `procedure_y` I want to get the average over all of those items `reaction_time_x` and `reaction_time_y`.

How can I do this with SPSS? I easily know how to compute averages in general, but in this case I have to select only a subset of the rows based on the conditions, and I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is not very clear. Please show the data themselves, maybe excerpt from the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your explanation I think one easy solution (without resorting to making new variables) would be to use `temporary` and `select if` statements to produce summary statistics for the desired categories. For instance, the below statement would produce the mean for `reaction_time_1` when the `category_1` and the `procedure_1` both equal 1 (and eliminate all other cases from the calculation which do not meet that criteria).

```
temporary.
select if category_1 = 1 and procedure_1 = 1.
freq var reaction_time_1 /statistics = mean.
execute.
```

Unless your procedures and categories are not mutually exclusive, there is surely a better way to organize your variables, but this will produce the requested output as is.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you want within-case means, so check out the mean transformation function.   You will still have to apply appropriate IF or DO IF tests, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a syntax of this sort for your scenario:

```
if (condition_x = condition_y & procedure_x = procedure_y) time_xy = mean (reaction_time_x, reaction_time_y) .
execute .
```

This would create a mean reaction time for conditions and procedures x and y when equal. Though it would only work if condition and procedure are variables (i.e. columns) in the datasets. If your data set is stacked, or shape in a person-period format (i.e. many rows per case) it won't work. For the cases in which procedure and condition are different, the created variable would be empty. Hope it works!